# Regex validation with decimal

Tags: regex, validation, laravel, laravel-4

Working on a regex validation, where I validate as XX,XX. With mine regex I can write 2,233 and it will still go through:

```
'regex:/[\d]{1,2},[\d]{2}/',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should add start and end limits as follows:

```
'regex:/^\d{1,3},\d{2}$/'
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/qW1cV2

Comment: What about if I want that it could be as XXX,XX also.

Comment: Ah, great! I tried 1,2,3, but the correct way is 1,3. Thanks :)

Comment: @user3185936, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you

Comment: @user3185936: FYI if the number of left-side digit isn't fixed you might as well use `+` (one or more) instead of `{1,3}`

Comment: Hmm! What do you mean? The number, could be all from 1 til 3 digits before comma, but only 2 after comma.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: This would still validate `2.233`, why is your demo different than your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This should validate any XX,XX

```
^(\d{2}),(\d{2})$
```